# c# console wont close after program ends

Tags: c#, .net

I have c# application that I am running, and then in some point application throws an error which is then catched, then app should end. And it ends, but console windows stays open...

I even checked in `windows task manager`, under `applications` tab, there is listed my console, but when I click `go to process`, there is no process of that application.

Thats weird... Application ended, process ended, but console stays on? How can I kill that console?

Edit: my code:

```
static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                //bunch of static methods from other static classes are being invoked

                Setup.Driver.Close();//another static method
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Setup.Driver.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Second edit:** Note: Process.Getprocess().Kill(), Application.Exit(), Environment.Exit() are not working for me, in windows task manager, there is no process left to kill, only console stays open!

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Have you used threads?

Comment: @Prashant: Posted my code in edit.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: What do you mean?

Comment: Have you created threads explicitly? Not enough code. Also, it is good idea to move `Setup.Driver.Close();` in to `finally` block and use once.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Explicitly, i don't think so... Although I am using selenium, which operates on a browser window, so maybe there are involved some external threads...

Comment: Using Environment.Exit(0) should have closed the application, unless you are using threads in your application as @HamletHakobyan stated or you are using Console.ReadLine() somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Prashant: Well then there probably is some threading involved that I don't know about. What now? :/

Comment: Are you trying to invoke another process from this application?

Comment: @Prashant: Okay, we can close this thread, I found out what was wrong. My app was executing another executable, and that executable was staying open. Now I need to find out how to kill external process... Thank for helping me tho!

Answer (score 6):

Environment.Exit and Application.Exit

Environment.Exit() is cleaner.

http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

Comment: To use Application.Exit() you need to include the reference of System.Windows.Form in your console application which by default is not necessary for a console app.

Answer (score 6):

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

or

```
this.Close();
```

If you have threads running, you can try this brute force method before you call Exit:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

foreach (var thread in currentThreads)
{
   thread.Interupt(); // If thread is waiting, stop waiting

   // or

   thread.Abort(); // Terminate thread immediately 

  // or

   thread.IsBackGround = true;
}
```

Comment: Not working, Process.GetProcess().Kill() is not working either. I think thats because process ends without any problems, just console window stays open.

Comment: in your `try` how did you close your application? did you use Console.ReadLine(); then Application.Exit();

Comment: I had to use `foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)` and then call `thread.Dispose();`. Looks like `thread.Finalize();` should work too. [ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread(v=vs.110).aspx ]

Comment: this code didn't work for me but killing the process that I started did.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

is the console app not closing when you start it from Visual Studio with the debugger attached or is it also not closed when you launch it from the file system / without attached debugger?

When the debugger is attached, you will always see an 'Press ENTER to exit ...' (or similar message).

When talking about the task manager - do you see the *.vshost process in there?
If yes, this is 'required' by Visual Studio and is not your 'real' console application; you will always see a *.vshost process when launching executables from within Visual Studio.

Hope this helps

Comment: :D That would be too easy. :) I tried turning off vshost, because that was the only thing that was staying in the process tree. Anyways after turning it off console still stays on, there just is no process left for that console. 
And as for the first question - program works fine within VS, console stays on only when I run it under my OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is most likely linked to another process which keeps it open.

In my case, the process was chromedriver.

Check your processes and your code to see what you opened and what's still running in the background.

Comment: Regarding your previous post which was deleted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996344/checking-array-size-using-event-driven-programming-in-javascript-node-js . You have XY problem. The thing you asked about doesn't make sense. *I need it to work side by side with the rest of my code.* - consider reasking the question with explaining your real problem in detail and providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Then it can be answered.

Comment: The process gets `killed` but then the console still stays open.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this issue too. Once I was done with the browser, I just used `Driver.Close();`  However, doing this still kept chromedriver running in the background. So instead I used **`Driver.Quit();`** . Then I made sure to **`return;`** from the Main method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I was stuck on this for 4 hours, the browser kept closing I never thought to check if the driver had closed as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
Environment.Exit();
```

will this work?

Comment: Not working, Process.GetProcess().Kill() is not working either. I think thats because process ends without any problems, just console window stays open.